# Js Function Parameters (highest value in a list of numbers)

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="test"> </p>
<script>

function numbers() {
  var qwe,
  zxc = - Infinity;
  // arguments.length == 4 , right?
  for (qwe = 0; qwe < arguments.length; qwe++) {        
    if (arguments[qwe] > zxc) {
      // If arguments[qwe] which is equalto11isgreaterthan - Infinity--TRUE, right ?
      zxc = arguments[qwe]; // why does the output become 25 ?
    }
  }
  return zxc; // is it because of this ?
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = numbers(13, 10, 25, 11);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the output become 25?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: It returns 25 because that's the highest of the arguments passed to `numbers()`...  Your code iterates through the parameters and selects the highest value.

Comment: I might be missing something, but doesn't this function compare each of the passed numbers to zxc, and only amends zxc  f the value is greater than the existing value  of zxc . Because 11 is not higher than 25, the value of zxc is 25, cos that was the highest value?

Comment: haha . Thanks for the explanation .
I get it finally, you bros . I owe you .

Comment: Ding and gavgrif are incorrect. This function does nothing other than what i've explained in my answer. This function does not get the greatest number of value.

Comment: How did you write the code if you didn't know what it does? O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments.length does equal 4, because you have sent in 4 arguments (13, 10, 25, 11). Your for loop iterates over the 4 arguments, and then finds arguments[qwe]. Let's break it down:

1. The first time through the for loop, qwe = 0 and zxc = - Infinity, so the if statement is evaluated to true (arguments[0] = 13, and 13 > - Infinity). Because the if statement is evaluated to true, we now evaluate the logic inside of the if statement, so zxc is now set to equal arguments[0], which is 13.
2. The next round through the for loop, qwe is now 1, zxc is still 13, and arguments[qwe] = 10 (the next argument). Now, arguments[qwe] = 10 which is not greater than zxc (13), so the if statement is false and the logic inside the if statement is not evaluated.
3. On the next iteration of the for loop, qwe = 2, zxc is still 13, and arguments[qwe] = 25 (the next iteration). Now, arguments[qwe] = 25 which is greater than zxc (13), so the if statement is true. Because the if statement is evaluated to true, we evaluate the logic inside the if statement and zxc is now set to equal arguments[2], which is 25.
4. For the next and final iteration of the for loop, qwe = 3, arguments[qwe] = 11, and zxc = 25. Because arguments[qwe] = 11, which is not greater than 25, the if statement evaluates to false and the logic inside the if statement is not evaluated.

At this point, qwe = the arguments length, so the for loop ends. Once the for loop ends, we return zxc, which at this point is 25.

Comment: Very descriptive step by step of the loop. +1

Comment: Thanks @MicahWilliamson :)

Comment: So the value of zxc will change after the evaluation of every iteration if the if statement is true :)

Comment: @mixsensei Yes, if the if statement is true, then zxc will be set to equal arguments[qwe] at that point

Comment: @JuliaNething Thanks ! I owe you . Sorry for english grammar . too Idiot to understand :/

Answer (score 0):

What you are returning with this loop is the greatest number that is passed as an argument to the function. Look at the numbers you have passed as arguments: `13, 10, 25, 11`.

Your loop is going through these passed integers and comparing them. The first index (`13` in this case) is being compared to negative infinity. Because it is greater, the `zxc` variable gets rewritten (which is what happens every time a current index is greater than the previous index). In your case, with `25` being the greatest integer in your argument list, it is the final value that is returned from the function.

**To test it out, change 11 to 29 and see what happens. 25 isn't the largest number anymore and doesn't get written to the `#test` element.**